# Grails spring security core, spring security rest IllegalStateException

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am getting this IllegalStateException when trying to make a http (get or post) call for some data to my server. I am building this application that consumes other application´s methods. Name app1 for the client, app2 for the server.
app2 has spring security core, spring security rest plugins. When I do the api/login, the token is rendered back to app1. Is ok to asume that the plugin handles the session already? Or should I handle it myself? 
Documentation is quite difficult to understand for me but I believe that is not clear. I am using the following versions of plugins

```
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
        compile ':spring-security-ldap:2.0.0'
        compile ':spring-security-rest:1.4.0', {
            excludes: 'spring-security-core'
        }
        compile ':cors:1.1.6'
```

I will paste error for one get call, this error is thrown for every call I do in my app1. Tell me if you need something else to help you to figure out my problem.

```
     Error |
2018-12-07 10:53:54,921 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResol
ver  - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /TERA/repor
te/getInstancias
Cannot create a session after the response has been committed. Stacktrace follow
s:
Message: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    Line | Method
->>   18 | doCall             in SecurityFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure3
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     99 | processFilterChain in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.Res
tTokenValidationFilter
|     66 | doFilter . . . . . in     ''
|     53 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsA
nonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    108 | doFilter . . . . . in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.Res
tAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication
.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.Res
tLogoutFilter
|     59 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityReques
tHolderFilter
|     82 | doFilter . . . . . in com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the scope of the service may cause this error, my scope is prototype and that is what is causing my error. I have changed it to session and it worked fine!
The problem was that some jobs that had to run did not. So i set back the scope to prototype.